# New warning in clojure on code I've been running for years invokeWithEnv NIYWARNING

Tags: clojure

I have a clojure program that interacts with Apple Mail via Applescript and Postgresql via the Korma clojure library.  Now, seemingly at random, I get a repeat of ca. 100 printed statements "invokeWithEnv NIYWARNING:"

StackOverflow, Bing, and Google return no hits for "invokeWithEnv NIYWARNING:"

Code is still running, just with the occasional random bursts of this apparently undocumented error message.

Comment: What exactly is your question?   That warning isn't really specific.  You need to figure out where in your code it does that and then when you're really stumped, do you ask here (while including your code and explanations).

Comment: Try updating the JDK you're running that program with. I can only find `invokeWithEnv` in old JDKs in the context of Apple Script, and "NIY" probably means "Not Implemented Yet", so without any more details it sounds that your macOS got updated and some legacy functionality got removed from Apple Script.

Comment: Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)